# iis 7 relative redirect with get parameters

Tags: iis-7, http-redirect

I have a http redirect in iis7  to send request to another domain. If url is something like `http://www.example.com/news/` it's ok but if i try `http://www.example.com/news/?id=3` then get parametes is deleted from string it's redirects to the same `http://www.example.com/news/`.
How to save get parameters in query string with iis7?

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://www.example.com" exactDestination="false" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you simply need to add '$S$Q' to the end of your redirect URL, e.g. destination="http://www.example.com$S$Q".

See also related StackOverflow question: [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)

Comment: You have to check the _"Redirect all requests to exact destination (instead of relative to destination)"_ too. Otherwise, the path part of the URL is appended twice.