# ASP.Net - Url Forwarding with Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, forwarding

I am developing a web site that uses a CMS and my actual home page is at mydomain.com/cms/home.aspx
When a user visits mydomain.com/index.aspx how to do I forward the site visitors to mydomain.com/cms/home.aspx?
One way is to create a dummy index.aspx with redirect to mydomain.com/cms/home.aspx but just wondering if there is a better way to do... may be in web.config or somewhere else!

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<redirect url="index.aspx" to="~/Pages/1/home.aspx"></redirect>
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirects: [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)

Rewrites: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Both are a bit of learning, but can be achieved in a reasonable amount of time.

You always have the option of writing your own. For rewrites, you can write an HTTPModule (or update your CMS's rewrite module). For redirects, you can use a custom 404 page to handle redirects. I have done both for DotNetNuke. Rolling my own took about 16 hours, but handles a few hundred thousand of each efficiently with caching.

Comment: Close but not exactly what I was looking for.. But +1 for that