# inline to handle url redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am migrating a site from siteA.domain.com to siteB.domain.com.  All the page paths remain the same.  The problem is it's a gradual migration, and not every path is being migrated at the same time.  So what I need to do is check the path the user is going to, and if it's a member of a list of migrated sites, then redirect the user from siteA.domain.com/path to siteB.domain.com/path

I was hoping to add in-line c# code to the master page.  Any thoughts/examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way would be to add some routes to the Global.asax.

```
       void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("home",
            "home",
            "~/Home.aspx");
    }
```

The above code will let you type "http://mysite.com/home" and it will redirect to the Home.aspx page.  You could redirect to http://myothersite.com/Home.aspx instead of using the ~, or relative path.

You can add routes for each and every page that you have in some master list.

Comment: I think he is using standard ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

I would have a list of address in your config that have been migrated, then in the page_load of the master page check the current url (on of the properties in `Request.Url` I can't remember which) and see if it is the list from the config.

Simple, but quite often the simple way is the best. Plus if it is a temporary thing there is no point wasting time doing anything complex.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use IIS for the redirect? SO Question - [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)

Answer (score 0):

Create an IHttpHandler that intercepts all incoming requests and redirects appropriately.