# IIS virtual directory pointing to wordpress blog hosted on another computer

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, virtual-directory

I have a windows box (which hosts www.example.com) and a linux box (which hosts wordpress blog).

Is there a way I can create a virtual directory on the windows box - so that when a user accesses www.example.com/blog, it gets the content from the linux server? ( I want the url in the browser to remain www.example.com/blog )

Thanks

Comment: Not easily ... it may require voodoo and magic. However, you could simply host wordpress on your window box.

Comment: thanks jrummell.. yes - that's what I was thinking - installing on the windows box will be the easiest.. but will look for few options before informing my manager about this.

Comment: This would be so much easier if the boxes were swapped over, iptables + squid and you're away.

Comment: @lynks how is introducing a proxy easier?

Comment: @jrummell I guess its one of those 'easy if you know how' situations. both pieces of software i mention could be configured in a matter of minutes for something like this. whereas i could stare for hours at iis and have no idea which button did what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with IIS, but if I had to deal with this problem, I would approach it from a routing point of view. Assuming that no session is maintained on the Windows box, requests for your directory could just be routed to the Linux box.

This would be very easy if you were able to use a subdomain (blog.example.com) rather than a directory, but it's still perfectly possible with a directory. You would need to route the traffic through something that could examine the HOST header, IE an http proxy like squid.

As a second thought, you could use mod_redirect to bounce the user from www.example.com/blog to blog.example.com, they could still land on the desired url, but would be redirected to the subdomain, not pretty, but it would make solving the issue trivial from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if what you are asking is possible. However, it would probably be much easier to simply [redirect from your windows box to your linux box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis). Why over complicate things?

Another option is to host [wordpress in IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress/) on windows.

Comment: you can install WordPress with web PI