# 301 Redirect for PDF file

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, iis-6

What's the easiest way to go about redirecting a URL like this:

```
http://domain.tld/my%20file.pdf
```

To another URL:

```
http://anotherdomain.tld/another%20file.pdf
```

This is a website and I do have access to IIS (6). Is there a way to do this just within IIS?

I've read a little about ISAPI plug-ins, though I've never done this. Is this the only way? I've been handed a site I haven't yet been able to build (just using Open Website... in VS 2010.) So I'm not even sure I can write an HTTP module if that's another option. My current error has something to do with an English section that has another web.config.

**Error 6   It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  C:\path\to\site\englishsubdirectory\app\Web.config**

Comment: redirect question: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true, check if this is of any help

Comment: @SreenathSoman Can you put that in an answer? I misread, and I just had to click down the file itself in IIS and add the redirect there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

check this : http://microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/

or this : [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)