# Redirect root URL - IIS 7

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I have some forums installed on my site at http://ironnoob.com/forums.

My website lives in c:\IronNoob and my forums are installed in c:\IronNoob\forums

I want both "ironnoob.com" and "www.ironnoob.com" to do a server-side redirect to "ironnoob.com\forums".

I'm using IIS 7 and I'm new to setting up this stuff so I don't even know what to google for. I know I can do a client-side redirect with HTML, but I understand that the server-side redirect is nicer. I've figured out how to install the HttpRedirect module for IIS, but if I set up a redirect in the root folder of my site to my forums folder, I get a circular redirect error when visiting ironnoob.com.

HTTP Redirect Settings:

1. root directory selected in Connections pane of ISS
2. Check "Redirect requests to this destination"
3. destination = http://somesite.com/forums
4. Check "redirect all requests to the exact location"
5. Check "only redirect requests to content in this directory (not subdirectories)"
6. Status code: Permanent (301)

Why is it redirecting subdirectories when I told it not to? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I guess you should google 301 redirect IIS. This is IIS 6 but this works the same way with IIS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/888356/1443490

Comment: The thing I'm most afraid of is setting up a circular reference - if somesite.com -> somesite.com/forums -> somesite.com/forums/forums -> etc

Comment: How is your IIS currently setup?

Comment: Ok, my mental model of the program was wrong. There's not a pile of global redirects, there's one for each node you're in in the site explorer pane. Got it working. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I was wrong again. I was getting a million nested redirects. Why is this so hard in IIS.

Comment: Is `forums` setup under your main site as a virtual folder/application? Or is it hosted somewhere else?

Comment: It's a real folder in my site's directory. I'm hosting the forum myself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis/888356#888356 lists 3 different cases, none of which is what I want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of using the `HTTP redirect` module, you can use the `URL rewrite` one.

Run the `inetmgr` command and select your website root. Open the `URL rewrite` configuration:

[image: URL rewrite configuration]

Click on `Add a rule` on the right panel. Select a `Blank rule` in inbound rules:

[image: Blank rule]

From here you have to name your rule and select the `Does not match the pattern` option. You then have to set the `Pattern` (in this case, it means that a URL not starting with `forums` will trigger this rule):

[image: Rule conditions]

The last step is to set up your redirect. You probably want to go with a 301 redirect as [advised by Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633):

[image: Redirect rule]

Click `Apply` on the right panel and you should be good to go.

**NOTE:** If your `Redirect URL` doesn't match your `Pattern` you will be stuck in an infinite loop (you can test it by simply clicking the `Test` button will writing your `Pattern`).

*Documentation for this module available [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)*

Comment: Cool - that works. It seems like it might be slightly more future-proof to regex an exact match on the root, so that if I in the future add a second root-level folder I can navigate to it. Is it possible to set this up without causing a circular rewrite?

Comment: If you want to add a second root-level folder simply put its rule first. The rules are processed in the order they are displayed (http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rules_Evaluation). I can edit the answer if you think that could be useful!