# IIS URL Rewrite down to a subfolder

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I need to get the IIS URL rewrite module to work but am having no luck.

What I need to do is 'inject' a subfolder (psms) into a url when it is not present, like so:
   https://something.somewhere.com/acp/default.aspx?k=v

Doesn't have the subfolder psms so redirect to   https://something.somewhere.com/psms/acp/default.aspx?k=v

Comment: See if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206273/redirect-root-url-iis-7/14263969#14263969

Answer (score 0):

OK, psms is a root folder of hosting ;
you need to use expression like

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="acp/default.aspx?k={R:1}" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't just thinking of the /acp/ example , I kind of need the psms to be included every time. So https://something.somewhere.com/admin/default.aspx?k=v also goes to https://something.somewhere.com/psms/admin/default.aspx?k=v