# Redirect to a subdomain from page

Tags: javascript, html, iis, redirect

Looking for the most transparent way (for the visitor) to be redirected to a subdomain from a page on the www site. IIS is the server. Example:

`www.mywebsite.com/cars` ---> `cars.mywebsite.com`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript might be a bit of a clunky solution.

I'd recommend you go with something on the server side that will be easier to maintain.

- Create the 'cars' directory
- Create an empty web.config in the 'cars' directory

Put the following contents into the web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://cars.mywebsite.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This probably won't work within visual studio's web server, but should be fine in IIS

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want the solution in javascript, then its pretty easy. Just find out the first JS file thats loaded and add this on the TOP

```
if(document.url == "www.mywebsite.com/cars")
window.location("cars.mywebsite.com");
```

Just mentioned since you've mentioned javascript and html in the tags...

Comment: There's an error in example. Use 
`window.location.assign("cars.mywebsite.com");`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for the redirect in IIS server, the answer may lie in this post:

[How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)

Answer (score 0):

imho htaccess would re-direct the user before any data is sent to the client.

Example: in teh root dir you want the user directed -from- place a file called .htaccess with the contents of:

```
#Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://cars.example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

Source: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Hope that helps Kurt.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for single solution - then @Riju's answer is a good one.

But for a more general solution, [URL Rewriter](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS is pretty powerful and will allow you to create rules things like this, and many more situations.