# IIS 6.0: How to add a site/app to a site taken over by WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, iis, iis-6, http-redirect

In my new job, I "inherited" a website that is completely implemented by WordPress. That is, every URL that starts with that `http://www.myjobdomain.com` is somehow redirected/generated by WordPress and, if a page does not exist in that location, it provided a 404.

I am now trying to add a "side site" to that domain, that is a web app (or a few html pages) that are outside that WordPress-based site.

Is there a way to accomplish that in IIS 6.0?

I know that in Apache I can play with .htaccess and redirect/rewrite rules to accomplish what I want. But in IIS 6.0 I could not find any way to do this.

If such a way exists, how would I go about to this? Any instruction or guidelines would be sincerely appreciated.

P.S. In my IIS Manager, I could not find any tabs alluded to by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888356/586707).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, all you need is to right-click your site in IIS Manager and select `Add Application...`.

Unless your site is already configured to relay all control to WP. In such case, you may want to look into Microsoft's [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module/extension.

Comment: Thanks. I would only add that after installing that extension, I needed to exist IIS Manager, then restart it, to see the URL Rewriter's icon.