# How to configure IIS server to host two applications one of which should be default

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, web

I have two applications:

- X.Web - Asp.net core 1.1 web application
- X.Api - ASP.NET WebApi2 application in .NET 4.6.1

Now they are both available as www.example.com/X.Web and www.example.com/X.Api respectively. My customer wants the web application to be available simply as www.example.com.

I tried a quick solution in my test environment - I just moved the content of X.Web folder to wwwroot and without any problems everything worked fine.

However, on my production server the web app works - htmls, scripts and styles are loaded correctly, but X.Api stops working - i get response

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title> IIS 502.5 Error </title>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "content">
            <div class = "content-container">
                <h3> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure </h3>
            </div>
            <div class = "content-container">
                <fieldset>
                    <h4> Common causes of this issue: </h4>
                    <ul>
                        <li> The application process failed to start </li>
                        <li> The application process started but then stopped </li>
                    <li> The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class = "content-container">
            <fieldset>
                <h4> Troubleshooting steps: </h4>
                <ul>
                    <li> Check the system event log for error messages </li>
                    <li> Enable logging the application process’ stdout messages </li>
                    <li> Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect </li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <h4> For more information visit:              
                    <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=808681">
                        <cite> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681 </cite>
                        </a>
                    </h4>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

for each and every request. In my Event log I can see:

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/DEFAULT WEB SITE/X.API' with 
physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\X.Api\' failed to start process 
with commandline '"dotnet" .\X.Web.dll', ErrorCode = 
'0x80004005 : 80008081.
```

The questions are:
1) what can be a problem
2) Why in the event log I can see ...failed to start process 
    with commandline '"dotnet" .**X.Web.dll**...
3) Is there any other way to achieve this simple requirement of my client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just to make sure I understand you properly, initially, you had: www.example.com/X.Web and www.example.com/X.Api, and X.Web was calling X.Api, right? Then you moved X.Web files from wwwroot/X.Web to wwwroot directly, and it worked on your env but not on the production env? Which version of IIS are you using?

1/ Maybe an idea: by moving X.Web maybe you have changed the user under which your X.Web application was running, making it unable to launch your ASP.NET Core application.

2/ My suggestion to 1 could explain, credentials issues.

3/ I would definitively avoid putting the file of X.Web directly under wwwroot and instead I would configure IIS to get a redirection from www.example.com to www.example.com/X.Wep. You could use [URL Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) (maybe an overkill in that case but it's a module that is very good to know in my opinion because it can help in various scenario) or simply configure IIS to redirect, this SO thread could be helping [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)

Comment: Yes - you understood it perfectly. I am using IIS 8.5 on both test and prod environment.

1, 2) - i dont think so (but not 100% sure). When both application were in their folders I could invoke Api from postman. As an experiment I COPIED the content from X.Web to the root folder and API stopped responding - every postman request was rejected. When I simply deleted the copied files, Api started to respond again to my postman requests.

3) I will definitely try the URL Rewrite module

Thank you.

Comment: I checked URL Rewrite - it works perfectly, thank you for your hint

Comment: No worries, it's a nice tool to have in your 'Répertoire', can be useful in numerous occasion. I'm currently using it to simulate a load balancer.