# IIS and C# making use of root route in a sub application

Tags: c#, iis

I have three applications (written in C#) hosting under one domain e.g. example.com/app1 example.com/app2 example.com/app3 through IIS.
There is nothing present at the root e.g. at example.com

Would it be possible for one of those applications to be accessed when someone tries to reach the root at example.com? Currently a 403 gets thrown if I try to access the root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)

Comment: I was hoping it would be possible in C# code rather than IIS configuration.

Comment: You said there is no app at the root, so no C# code to begin with. You can write yet another C# app and put it into the root to perform the redirection.

Comment: I might be forced to do that, yeah. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you could write a asp.net application e.g webform or MVC or else at the root of the  example.com website in the IIS.

For the webform.

You could create a index.aspx page in the root path.

Then you could use `response.redirect`  to redirect the url to one of your application.

Details codes as below:

```
public partial class welcome : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://example.com/app1");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm settling on, yeah. I'll have to run it by the software architects though, since it's adding IIS configuration. Alas.