# IIS redirect URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How to redirect https://hr.test.in/old-test-contact to https://www.test.in/info/contactus ?

I tried the following rule but it does not work.

```
 <rule name="new rule" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="*" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="hr.test.in" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.test.in/info/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```

When I use the above rule I am redirected to https://www.test.in/info/old-test-contact.

However the below redirect works fine with above rule.

https://hr.test.in/vacancies to https://www.test.in/info/vacancies

Any ideas how I can get  https://hr.test.in/old-test-contact to https://www.test.in/info/contactus working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to redirect a URL path in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis)

Comment: `old-test-contact` is captured into R:0 - perhaps instead you should add a condition to check if the path is `old-test-contact` and redirect to /contactus, no capturing required

Answer (score 0):

According to your matching rules, {R:0} at this time should be old-test-contact, You can use the Test Pattern in IIS to view the value of {R:0}:

[image]

You can try to use this URL Rewrite Rule:

```
       <rule name="new rule" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="hr.test.in" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.test.in/info/contactus" />
        </rule>
```