# how to create rule for iis redirection to www1 -> www

Tags: redirect, iis

how to create rule for *IIS* redirection **www1 domain to www**.
example www1.xyz.com -> [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888325/how-to-redirect-a-url-path-in-iis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect from www1 to www, you can refer to this link:

```
<rule name="redirect to www" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(.*)$" />
     <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www1.example.com" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```